# Return derived class object in the script whereas original function declaration returns parent class in C++

Tags: c++

A function `GetCarPrice()` has a return type of a class `Money` where the function is declared, and this method is not declared within `Money`, meaning it's not a member function of this class.

Later, I derive another class from `Money`, defined as `Dollar`, with some additional attributes and methods.

Now, I want to return `Dollar` type object when using the function `GetCarPrice()` inside the main function, keeping the declaration of this function the same.

Here is a brief pseudo code:

```
class Money {...}; `
class Dollar: public Money {...};

Money* GetCarPrice () {...};

int main()
{
   Dollar* D1;
   ...
   D1 = GetCarPrice(); // Here I get error: invalid conversion from Money to Dollar
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to do this in C++?

N.B. I am new to this platform, please pardon my mistakes. Please do not close it, I need help. TIA.

Comment: No there is not, because a `Money` is not a `Dollar`, so a `Dollar` pointer can't point to just a `Money`. Why does `GetCarPrice` return a `Money`? What does a `Money` represent? How would you make a `Dollar` from a `Money`? What would the values of the additional attributes you mention be after this conversion?

Comment: Basically I am working on modifying a script for my research project. In that script I am adding some additional features to a specific class (Money), so I derived a new class (Dollar) from it. Inside that script, there is a function (GetCarPrice) which returns that class (Money). I need to change the return type to the new class (Dollar) else it does not get consistent with the rest of modifications. Changing the return type for the function at the point of declaration is also complicated because this function is connected to other components of the project which I cannot touch.

Comment: Your best option is to figure out a good interface and use `virtual` member functions.

Comment: In your example, `Dollar` is an instance of the `Money` type. Put another way, anything that is a `Dollar` object is also a `Money` object; but notably, the reverse is _not_ necessarily true (what if you were to also derive a `Peso` type from the `Money` type?). I don't think there's any to do what you're asking, unfortunately.

Comment: Would a calling a cast work on the result of `GetCarPrice()`, such as `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is completely wrong, @oraqlle. For a `static_cast`, you would need to somehow know that the `Money*` points to a `Dollar`. Maybe a `dynamic_cast`, which relies on `Money` being polymorphic. The best option is to write code in a way that does not rely on any specific currency. In that context, I'd also ask why you think you need a `Dollar*` in your code, because that may be closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Okay okay. I tried in godbolt and it worked but I figured it was due to me making `Money` and `Dollar` trivial in the "test" I ran. I completely forgot about `dynamic_cast` being the polymorphic kind cast, which was the idea I was going for. Thank you for providing the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a **Dollar** instance and return the pointer of it in the **GetCarPrice()**.

If there are some legacy code that creates a **Money** instance and you want to keep it, you should convert the object like this.(If the **Money** class has a copy constructor, it will be easy because you can call it at the constructor of the **Dollar**.)

```
class Dollar : public Money {
...
    Zzz zzz;
public:
    Dollar(const Money &money) : Money(money) {
        zzz = transform_xxx_yyy_to_zzz(money.xxx, money.yyy);
        ...
    }
}


Money* GetCarPrice ()
{
    ...
    Money* money = ...;
    if (...) { // If you should convert to a Dollar.
        Dollar* dollar = new Dollar(*money);
        delete money; // This prevents a memory leak.
        return dollar;
    }
    return money;
}
```

And you can safely cast a **Money** pointer to a **Dollar** pointer like this.

```
Money* m = GetCarPrice();
Dollar* d = dynamic_cast<Dollar*>(m);
if (d) {
    // the m is actually a Dollar, so do whatever with the d.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dynamic cast serves my purpose!